# Uninstalling an Application takes too long

Tags: visual-studio-2008, time, long-integer, uninstallation

Based on title, this question may seems more fitting for superuser, but I am concerned about the development perspective.

I have created an installer that installs a small App, size about 8 MB. It is created using Visual Studio 2008. Crystal Report is added as a prerequisite, and few other common prerequisites not worth mentioning.

Is there some kind of settings or nature of the installer that could cause such a delay. The un installer becomes unresponsive towards the end, until it fully completes.

Comment: How long are we talking about here?

Comment: 40 seconds. Depending of machine even longer, sometimes long enough to be declared as hanged.

Comment: Does this slowness occur on all major versions of Windows? (XP, Vista and 7)

Comment: It occurs with windows XP, haven't tested with others.